# Behavior of writing to TCP socket before reading all data

Tags: linux, sockets, http, tcp

I've been writing small specific purpose HTTP servers for some applications of mine, and I noticed that, if you `write()` before you `read()` all available data, the bytes are not sent properly. For example, after `read()`ing *only* the request line (`GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n`) sent by my browser, I `write()`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Connection: close\r\r
Content-Type: text/html\r\n
\r\n
(some HTML stuff)
```

Wireshark capture of this `write()`:

[image]

`'\n'` bytes and `Content-Type` header are gone! (Wireshark always displays `'\n'` bytes in HTTP header section, if they exist)

And the browser do not displays the HTML content.

So I should never `write()` before `read()` everything? Is this the TCP standard?

Edit 1: adding my C++ code that sends the stuff:

```
string header =
  "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
  "Connection: close\r\r"
  "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
  "\r\n"
;
write(sd, header.c_str(), header.size()); // from unistd.h
FILE* fp = fopen("index.html", "rb");
char by;
while (fread(&by,1,1,fp) == 1) write(sd,&by,1);
fclose(fp);
```

Edit 2: Well, @selbie pointed a typo... `"Connection: close\r\r"`. After fixing it, the behavior has changed, to a less scary one: the `write()` is actually not sending data at all. Now, Wireshark only displays the request! No response (from my `write()`) is captured.

Edit 3: As suggested by @usr, I wrote a small test client... When the server `read()`s everything before `write()`ing, the client **always** receives all the HTTP payload. When the server `write()`s before `read()`ing the headers sent by the client, the client **never** receives the whole HTTP payload. I did **many** tests!

When the server `write()`s **after** `read()`ing the headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Connection: close\r\n
Content-Type: text/html\r\n
\r\n
<form>\n
  <input type="text" name="field1" />\n
  <input type="text" name="field2" />\n
  <input type="submit" value="send" />\n
</form>\n
```

When the server `write()`s **before** `read()`ing the headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Connection: close\r\n
Content-Type: text/html\r\n
\r\n
<form>\n
  <input type="text" name="field1" />\n
  <input
```

and:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Connection: close\r\n
Content-Type: text/html\r\n
\r\n
<form>\n
  <input type="text" name="field1" />\n
  <input type="text" name="field2" />\n
  <input type="submit"
```

and:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Connection: close\r\n
Content-Type: text/html\r\n
\r\n
<form>\n
  <input type="tex
```

I ran the client like 50 times with each setting.

Why is this happening??? It **has** to be something with the kernel...

Edit 4: Another thing I noticed doing these tests... Wireshak **always** displays both request and response, if the server `read()`s the headers, but **always** displays only the request, if the server do not `read()` the headers. Seriously, this has to do with TCP.

Comment: Your Connection header is terminated with two CRs rather than CR-LF, which is probably confusing wireshark and maybe the browser.

Comment: I fixed that, see the edits, please.

Comment: One other potential bug you have here.  You do not seem to be checking the return values of your `read` and `write` calls.  These calls can fail and return -1 for all kinds of reasons.  More important - the calls to read/write can return a value to indicate partial data.

Answer (score 2):

You should not write the response before reading the request. You are violating the HTTP protocol.

That said I don't know why the browser would behave like that. In any case stop violating the HTTP protocol.

TCP is a bidirectional stream of bytes. It does not care when and what is written. This is not a TCP-level issue.

I'm not sure what I'm seeing on that screenshot. If you mean the missing `\n` chars that certainly was not stripped by the kernel. The kernel has no business interfering with the data you are sending. It does not know what the data means.

Your app has a bug. Maybe you are using some library that "helpfully" converts the line endings to Linux format?! Impossible to answer without code. This answer is as good as it gets with the information posted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but... Do you understand what the wireshark capture means? It means that TCP *did not* send properly the bytes I requested it to send! Is *has* to be a TCP level issue. If I send the exact same octets, but after `read()`ing all bytes in the TCP socket (and I still don't even parse these HTTP request bytes), everything works. So this is just a TCP matter. It can't be "me not following the HTTP protocol".

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm seeing on that screenshot. If you mean the missing \n chars that certainly was not stripped by the kernel... Your app did that. Btw, is the downvote from you?

Comment: My library is C++'s `std::string` and `<unistd.h>`'s `write()`.

Comment: (I edited my question with the code)

And the `'\n'` bytes are not stripped if I `read()` all data before doing the `write()`.

Comment: You'll eventually discover that your app sent wrong bytes or you were looking at the wrong connection or the wrong code or or or... Maybe you can experiment by replacing *all* code with `write("a\nb", 3)`. Replace as much as possible.

Comment: Why does it seems plausible to you that TCP is changing the bytes in any way? TCP does not know what they mean. Lines mean nothing to TCP.

Comment: Well, if I knew the answer to this strange behavior, I wouldn't be asking... But I know that if I do the exact same thing, but **`read()`ing before `write()`ing**, everything is sent correctly. And this is just a test application. Is just a C++ `main()`. There is **nothing** else.

Comment: I'm not familiar with C APIs but I think you can configure the API to treat line endings specially. That's why you had to use b in rb. Is the socket FD configured appropriately? How sure are you that Wireshark is displaying the correct bytes? Maybe you should write a test client.

Comment: Ok, I'll write a test client and see the behavior... When I'm done, I'll edit the question with the results.

Comment: @matheuscscp so the headers always were transferred correctly, right? The truncated response looks like you assumed that read would read all bytes that you expect. It will read in arbitrary chunks of at least one byte, though. Maybe you should post full code for server and client.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Connection` header ends with `\r\r` instead of `\r\n`  That explains the weirdness in your Wireshark trace.

Instead of this;

```
"Connection: close\r\r"
```

Change it do this:

```
"Connection: close\r\n"
```

Comment: He's seeing no \r\n at all.

Comment: He should start with fixing his typo.  I'm reasonably certain that will clear up most of his issues.

Comment: Would be an interesting explanation. I'm not trusting Wireshark either.

Comment: Thanks! I'll test fixing the typo!

Comment: @selbie The behavior has changed after fixing the typo... See my 2nd edit, please!

Answer (score -1):

Well... Seems like the kernel has the following policy, which I discovered only by empirical testing, putting a `sleep(1)` before `close()`.

If there is nothing left to be `read()`, and you immediately call `write()` and `close()`, the kernel will send everything properly, no problem.

But if there is stuff to be `read()` and you `write(); close()`, the kernel will stop sending the data, like if you just decided to stop the conversation abruptly. The kernel kinda thinks "well... he didn't even `read()` this stuff I'm holding and he's closing the socket... he probably also wants me to stop sending this stuff he told me to send". Stupid kernel!

Comment: Nothing stupid about it. TCP (not 'the kernel') resets the connection if you close it while there is data pending to be read. This is well-defined behaviour. What is stupid here is violating the HTTP protocol in all the numerous ways you are doing, starting with ignoring the request.

Comment: I'm not violating HTTP. I'm asking a question about my home experiment, for my own personal learning. It doesn't matter what goes through TCP. The observed behavior, as you mentioned, will always happen, even if no application level protocol is implemented. The question is, as the title says, about TCP, not about HTTP. So... Stupid is downvoting and criticizing an answer that, despite being based on empirical testing (given my lack of theoretical knowledge about TCP), is correct and "solves my problem". It **IS** the kernel resetting the connection, because **THE KERNEL** implements TCP.

Comment: You didn't mention in your question that you are closing the connection before you read it. That's just wrong and any good text on socket programming will explain it.

Comment: I was about to post that same page.

Comment: Interesting resolution to this question. This was not a hypothesis that I was able to come up with. Complete code would have shown the problem, though.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think about the close() in the beginning... But, all of a sudden! Haha